# GitHub Pull Request complex conflicts

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

GitHub added a feature about a month ago to resolve merge conflicts on the web interface, however it only works for "simple" merge conflicts:

**No conflicts**
[image: GitHub Pull Request - No conflicts]

**Simple conflicts**

[image: GitHub Pull Request - Resolve simple conflicts]

**Complex conflicts**

[image: GitHub Pull Request - Resolve complex conflicts]

In the [blog post](https://github.com/blog/2293-resolve-simple-merge-conflicts-on-github) that introduced the new feature, GitHub mentions competing line changes, which can range from fairly simple to quite complex.

What qualifies as a conflict too complex to resolve in the web editor?

Comment: have you asked to github support?

Comment: Happened to me too. And these is no conflict at all. I just can't merge my pull request...

Comment: I am seeing the same problem, and according to this [page](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line), I opened those files in command line. But I did not see the conflicts. I am still not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to happen if any files were renamed, I had a pull request that included renamed files showing the same message and as soon as I named the files back and committed that the "Resolve conflicts" became available again

Comment: So, what to do then? Just cancel the pull request, merge locally, and push? Or can the PR later be linked to the pushed merge commit? _(Sorry if I'm totally confused, never seen a PR from the inside...)_ UPDATE (1 min. later...): Oh, I see, PRs are no magic, they are just like issues... Nothing to do with Git itself, actually. Correct?